# Creating fixed subviews outside of uiscrollview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm attempting to put a generic view above and a tab bar underneath a scroll view, but can't figure out how to do it. Can someone explain how to properly place these constraints? Ideally I would like a solution non-programmatically, i.e. one that uses the storyboard. Thanks!

I've applied no constraints so far.

This is the desired output:

[image: this is my desired output.]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your view showing the constraints you applied.

Comment: Check my edit, I placed the output of what I want. I've applied no constraints so far.

Comment: Check the answer below. But to be honest you don't really need to apply constraints. If your maths is right the same can be achieved without constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Well, In a UITabbarVC

Add UIView constraint top, leading and trailing to the self.view and assign height constraint to about 30% of self.view.height

Add UIScrollView add constraint bottom, leading, trailing to self.view and top constraint to bottom of the added UIView

Answer (score 0):

First you have to give leading, trailing, top and a height constraint to your top view like so:

[image: top view constraints]

Then you need to give your scrollview, top, leading, trailing and bottom constraints like this:

[image]

And finally you give your tabbar leading, trailing and bottom constraints as shown:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need *three* things

1. `UITabBarController`
2. `UIView`
3. `UIScrollView`

Now, Firstly, you need to go in your `.storyboard` file and *drag and drop* a `UITabBarController` from the *left hand panel*

**NOTE:** If you are using XCode 10 , then that *panel* is renamed as `Library` which is available at the *top bar* with a *Apple Home Button* type button

Now, when you dragged `UITabBarController`, you will get some `View Controllers` attached with it by default.

*Drag and drop* a `UIView` to one of the view controller( preferably the first one) and set some `Auto Layout` constraints by selecting that *View* and clicking on the **Add New Constraints** button in the bottom bar ( where your *Current zoom size* is available) . You can add the following constraints :

1. Leading (aka left) = 0
2. Top = 0
3. Trailing (aka right) = 0

> You also need to provide a **height** .

If you want to provide a constant height, then you can provide it using the same **Add New Constraints** option

However, if you want to provide a variable height like in **Percentage** , then hold `Control` on keyboard and click and drag from *View* that you dragged previously to the `View Controller`'s ***View*** . Select the option `Equals Height`. Now it will take the height of the complete *View Controller* as it is taking 100% of the height of *View Controller* by default and we need to change that.

To change that, click on the *View* again , click *Hide/Show inspectors* (available on the top right corner) and select `Size Inspector` . There will be a constraint named **Height** which will be *shown equal to superview* . Click on the **Edit** button next to it and change the value of *text field* named **Multiplier** to the percent you want (make sure the value of **constant** *text field* is 0). If you want the height to be 20%, then input 0.2 and so on.

Next, You need to drag and drop a `UIScrollView` **just below** the custom *view* (that we just created and added the constraint to). Now set the constraints for the **Scroll View** in the same way you did for **View**.

For the **Scroll View**, you need to set the following constraints :

1. Leading (aka left) = 0
2. Top = 0
3. Trailing (aka right) = 0
4. Bottom = 0

and hit the **Add Constraints** button.

Now you will get the desired output . The only thing that will remain will be changing the colour of the `View` and changing the text label and icons for the `UITabBarController` items. You can change that via `Storyboard` easily.

Do let me know if you need any further assistance!